# Webform check permission

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have a CiviCRM Webform that creates a contact with some custom fields on submission.
It throws DB Constraint error intermittently

On Webform submission I get this error:
The Druapl Reports Logs shows:

"The CiviCRM "contact create" API function returned the error: "A fatal error was triggered" when called by line 618 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc with the following parameters: "Array ( [contact_sub_type] => Array ( [Invoice_No] => Invoice_No ) [webform_label] => Invoice [id] => -268 [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 ) "

However, if the same user creates a Contact using the civicrm form, there is no error.

Comment: What versions of CiviCRM and Webform/CiviCRM?

Comment: I am also getting what seems like it may be a similar error on Webform/Civi integration. I am on Civi 4.6.10 and the latest webform and webform-civi. > The CiviCRM "group_contact create" API returned the error: "Mandatory > key(s) missing from params array: group_id" when called by function > "saveGroupsAndTags" on line 822 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc with > parameters: "Array ( [contact_id] => 4655 [group_id] => > [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 ) "

Comment: Did you take a look at permissions. It looks like it has to do with invoices. Did you enable the invoice feature? Is the download invoice permissions enabled for that user level?